# Does it make sense to use ifdef linux etc in header?

Tags: c, macros, cross-platform, software-design

I read some articles about using `#ifdef #elif` etc macro in order to provide implementation for various platforms and almost everyone says that it should be avoided if possible because it is hard to maintain. However I am currently considering its usage in header file as follows:

```
#ifdef __linux__
    typedef struct my_linux_struct my_struct 
#elif __APPLE__
    typedef struct my_macos_struct my_struct 
#else
    #error Platform not supported
#endif
```

Inspite of serving the same purpose the implementation of `struct my_linux_struct` and `struct my_macos_struct` is completely different.

So I have a dedicated `c` file for each platform where the platform's struct (either `struct my_linux_struct` or `struct my_macos_struct`) is defined.

The benefit I sew from naming the struct differently is to avoid name collision in the implementation.

Is it a common practice to write conditional macro like that? Or we should avoid writing such things whenever possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it a common practice to write conditional macro like that? Or we should avoid writing such things whenever possible.

Half way between the two.

Better to put the difference in the .c file, yet  not something to avoid "whenever possible".

Keeping platform specific code out of .h files is better, yet not a *law*.

Comment: _keeping platform specific code out of .h files is better_ do you mean only public headers? Or private ones as well?

Comment: @St.Antario Public ones more so.

Comment: Better yet, don't have it at all.

Comment: @R.. You mean such macros? So as far as I can tell it is _almost_ always preferable to design with interfaces since such `#ifdef`s is very hard to maintain....